# 'FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop/FIRCoreDiagnosticsData.h' file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have a Swift project using Firebase and Cocoapods. I am not able to find the root cause of this error message that shows up as build error

```
#import <FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop/FIRCoreDiagnosticsData.h>
```

Error message:

> 'FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop/FIRCoreDiagnosticsData.h' file not found

The FIRCoreDiagnosticsData.h file is in Pods->FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop hierarchy, but for some reason Xcode cannot find it. Help please.

Comment: I currently have this problem on my CI but not on my personal machine, which suggests that it is a problem with the environment. Try cleaning derived data, quitting Xcode, and restarting your machine.